# MySQL hierarchical recursive query

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть таблица [image: table_staff]

мне надо давать staff_id и взять все ее parent_staff, прошу помоч,заранее спасибо

Comment: _мне надо давать staff_id и взять все ее parent_staff_ - вот это поясните. Кому давать? и как? что значит "взять"?

Comment: @Akina видимо на вход подавать staff_id, находить parent_staff(вывести) - потом найти его parent_staff(вывести), etc

Comment: @SLy_huh Хотелось бы всё это (или не это, а что-то иное) увидеть в исполнении автора. Причём в тексте вопроса.

Comment: @Akina, ИМХО, вопрос о рекурсии по делу, независимо от того насколько коряво он задан. Хотелось бы увидеть мнение Гуру от SQL, что нужно делать в таких случаях.

Comment: Почему у записи ID=12 в родителях она сама ?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов На самом деле ответов про рекурсию в MySQL на этом ресурсе довольно много. Основных подходов 2: хранимая процедура, последовательно накапливающая результат. И накопление ID родителей в переменной, но тут есть сложности, что оно идеально работает когда ID детей всегда больше, чем родителей, иначе надо домножать стартовую выборку на таблицу с количеством записей равному количеству уровеней рекурсии

Comment: @Mike вот по моему это то, что нужно для юного падавана :). Далеко не все вообще слышали слово "рекурсия". В данном случае я бы конечно написал хранимую процедуру, но человек хотел запрос :)

Comment: Да мне надо на вход подавать staff_id, находить parent_staff(вывести) - потом найти его parent_staff(вывести) и тд....

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов прочитав внимательно вопрос и комментарий автора я вдруг понял, что в данном случае можно ограничится "циклом". вот буквально, как написано, берем запись, ее parent и повторяем это в цикле ... и никакой рекурсии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как нам надо двигаться по дереву от потомка к родителю, то на каждом уровне иерархии у нас добавляется всего одна запись. Так что нам вообще не нужна рекурсия, а нужен цикл который на каждом шаге получит родителя текущей записи.

Циклов в SQL не бывает, так что будем его эмулировать с помощью произвольной таблицы (или запроса) который выдаст количество строк, достаточное для получения всех родителей. В данном примере я решил в качестве такого курсора использовать уникальные parent_staff из таблицы, так как их заведомо не меньше, чем нужно итераций "цикла". Если известна максимально возможная глубина иерархии лучше (для быстродействия) ограничить его limit.

```
select distinct id
  from (
    select @id:=(select parent_staff from staff where staff_id=@id) id
      from (select distinct parent_staff from staff) as curs,
           (select @id:=2 /* стартовый staff_id */ ) A
) B
```

Comment: Спасибо получилось супер

Comment: Mike где это скажите я сделаю! зеленая галочка

Answer (score 2):

```
with recursive tree (TABLE, staff_id, level, pathstr)
as (select TABLE, staff_id, 0, cast('' as text) 
   from tree_sample
   where staff_parent_staff is null 
union all
   select tree_sample.TABLE, tree_sample.staff_id, t.level + 1, tree.pathstr + tree_sample.TABLE
   from tree_sample 
     inner join tree on tree.staff_id = tree_sample.staff_parent_staff) 
select staff_id, space( level ) + TABLE as TABLE 
from tree 
order by pathstr
```

Comment: А, где требуемая рекурсия для  staff_id про всех родителей ?

Comment: про это в вопросе вроде не написано

Comment: Неправда, написано. Неявно по тексту (_и взять **все** ее parent_staff_) и явно в заголовке.

Comment: @Pavel Bereznichenko, а в заголовке этого разве не было?

Comment: Ага сходу не нашел всех скрытых смыслов, исправил)

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko А ничего, что with recursive в MySQL есть только в экспериментальных версиях, которые на продакшене найти пока нереально

Comment: @Pavel Bereznichenko - снимаю минус в Вашего ответа :). Тем не менее присоединяюсь к Mike

Comment: И кстати интересно, оно не зациклится на записи с ID=12, у которой parent она сама....

Comment: не должно, пускай проверяет)

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсивных запросов в stable у MySQL пока нет, так что только ХП.

С другой стороны, рекурсия тут не нужна, от слова "совсем". Схематичненько ежели, то будет где-то так:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_all_parents(IN child_id BIGINT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_parents;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_parents(id BIGINT UNIQUE) ENGINE=Memory;
    INSERT INTO tmp_parents(id) SELECT child_id;
    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp_parents) > cnt
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM tmp_parents;
        INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp_parents(id)
            SELECT parent_id 
            FROM datatable 
            WHERE id IN (
                        SELECT id FROM tmp_parents
                        );
    END WHILE;
    /* DELETE FROM tmp_parents WHERE id = child_id; */
    SELECT id FROM tmp_parents;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_parents;
END;
```