# mysql запрос на выборку с IN, и возможностью "break"нуться

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос, для примера:

```
SELECT `id`,`id_category` 
FROM `items` 
WHERE `id_category` IN(22333,23433,23454 и т.д) 
AND `public` = 1
```

В каждой id_category может быть множество id где public == 1
Вопрос: Можно ли написать sql, по которому mysql найдя первый id c public = 1, переходил к следующей id_category в списке? т.е. не нужно искать все записи , а только по 1ой в каждой категории.

EXPLAIN Запросa с DISTINCT:
[image: EXPLAIN Запросa с DISTINCT]

EXPLAIN Запросa БЕЗ DISTINCT:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас неверное представление о работе MySQL.

Comment: Зачем? Чего Вы хотите достичь?

Comment: Хочу оптимизировать запрос, т.к. мне не нужны все записи, мне важен лишь факт наличия хотябы одного id под данной категорией, а таблица огромная , и запрос будет выполнятся очень медленно т.к. в описанном примере будут искаться все id

Comment: А сам id вам при этом нужен ? может `select distinct id_category from ...` при наличии индекса по полям `(id_catgory, public)` должно быстро отработать.

Comment: Добавьте индекс на поле `id_category` (или составной индекс `id_category, public` - нужно смотреть план) и запрос будет летать

Comment: индексы есть. DISTINCT подойдет, выполняется за 65ms. Но хотелось бы за макс. 5мс )
Правда разница между DISTINCT и без него всего ~4mc  :)

Comment: В обоих случаях затрагивается одинаковое кол-во строк

Comment: План выполнения с distinct и без него приведите. надо посмотреть использует ли он индекс и как

Comment: привел скрины , выше в вопросе

Comment: А что за индекс у вас `id_category` ? Я предлагал сделать составной индекс из двух полей (id_category, public)`. А иначе ему все равно приходится лезть в данные по каждому этому id что бы проверить public

Comment: И если индекс ipublic состоит только из 1 поля public, то удалите его. У него крайне низкая селективность и если какой нибудь запрос все таки (что вряд ли) захочет его использовать он будет работать дольше, чем полным перебором таблицы (при условии что у поля public, как я подозреваю, очень мало возможных значений)

Comment: А где вы берёте вот этот вот список категорий? Из другого запроса? Может быть их можно объединить?

Comment: – Mike, Точно, я  забыл про составные индексы :) Сделал составной, и запрос выполняется ~ 25ms , но разница между дистинкт и без него - таже.

Comment: – vp_arth, Да, это другой запрос, он вызывается в php в рекурсивной функции , которая собирает все дочернии категории из дерева. Ведь в MySQL нет рекурсивного запроса, так ? )

Comment: В общем виде их в MySQL (кроме совершенно новой версии, которая вроде как еще бета или что то типа того) их конечно нет. Но в некоторых случаях можно придумать приемлемые по скорости решения. как например тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613283

Comment: Как вариант еще можно попробовать `select id from XX where exists(select 1 from id_category where id_category=XX.id and public=1)` где XX таблица категорий где id_category уникальны

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(`id`) `id`,`id_category` 
FROM `items` 
WHERE `id_category` IN (22333,23433,23454) 
  AND `public` = 1
GROUP BY `id_category`
```

Comment: Почти то что нужно, да , я получу по одной записи из каждой категории, но mysql в этом случае все равно пройдется по всем записям , чтобы вычислить мин id. А мне для полной красоты (в плане оптимизации, уменьшения времени на запрос) хотелось бы , чтобы mysql не делал этого.
Но похоже это не реально, и я действительно не верно представляю себе работу mysql

Comment: `mysql в этом случае все равно пройдется по всем записям , чтобы вычислить мин id` - ну так создайте необходимый индекс, какие проблемы?