# Как выбрать рефералов с таблицы?

Tags: mysql, php7

Помогите пожалуйста. Не знаю как выбрать рефералов пользователя по уровням с БД.

Выбрать рефералов первой линии могу, а вот как вывести других без понятия. 
Например мой id = 7 тут я делаю выборку .

```
$sql_select_partners = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE referrer='7'";
$result_partners  = mysqli_query($db,$sql_select_partners) or die("Ошибка: " . mysqli_error($db));


while($partnerinfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_partners)) 
{
  echo $partnerinfo["login"]."<br>";
}
```

И получаю рефералов своего первого уровня, но например мой реферал который у меня в первом уровне тоже имеет у себя рефералов, для него они будут рефералами первого уровня, но для меня второго. Как вывести рефералов от первого до пятого уровня? Нужно сделать выборку в 5 уровней.

Вот сама таблица.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рефералов первой линии выбирал так

Comment: @Mike отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: Что вы все так mysql любите. он практически единственная БД которая на это совершенно не рассчитана. в общем что нибудь вроде этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/613313/194569 (вместо `select distinct parent_staff from staff` в запросе использовать `select 1 from tabX limit 7` для 7 уровней, где tabX любая таблица в которой более 7 записей)

Comment: Хотя вам наверно с другой стороны дерево обходить надо, тогда что то вроде этого: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/634545/194569 Ну или полный обход дерева https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/673240/194569  в общем в зависимости от нюансов в данных запрос может кардинально изменятся, хотя общая идея там одна и та же

Comment: Изменение таблицы к "деревянному" виду не рассматривается? Хотя бы nested sets из неё сделать. Или хотя бы добавить поле level, чтобы при добавлении строки устанавливать его как +1 от level родителя