# (MySQL) Получить список всех под компании (несколько уровней)

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица со списком компании и их под компании.
Мне нужно получить список всех под компании всех уровней.

---

Вот структура таблицы:

`CREATE TABLE companies (
  id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  parent_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL
);`

insert into `companies` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) values('1','#NAME-PARENT-1',NULL);
insert into `companies` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) values('2','#NAME-1','1');
insert into `companies` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) values('3','#NAME-2','1');
insert into `companies` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) values('4','#NAME-3','2');
insert into `companies` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) values('5','#NAME-4','2');
insert into `companies` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) values('6','#NAME-5','3');
insert into `companies` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) values('7','#NAME-6','3');
insert into `companies` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) values('8','#NAME-7','6');
insert into `companies` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) values('9','#NAME-8','6');
insert into `companies` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) values('10','#NAME-9','7');
insert into `companies` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) values('11','#NAME-10','7');
insert into `companies` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) values('12','#NAME-PARENT-2',NULL);

Вот пример кода как я получаю все под компании:

```
SELECT list
FROM (
        SELECT 
                @IDS AS list,
                @IDS := (
                        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`)
                        FROM `companies`
                        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`parent_id`, @IDS)
                ) as d
        FROM `companies`,
        (SELECT @IDS := 1) as v
)
as a
WHERE list IS NOT NULL;
```

Результат:

```
1
2,3
4,5,6,7
8,9,10,11
```

---

Ну да. все отлично.. Но не тут-то было

Мне нужно получить тот же результат без использования:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(`id`)
```

Если есть какие либо идеи или же примеры кода(
Заранее большое спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Как нибудь от потомков попробовать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/613313/194569 Или как нибудь так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/673240/194569 А вообще для работы  с подобными структурами надо БД менять. MySQL практически единственная, в которой нет рекурсии из коробки

Comment: *MySQL практически единственная, в которой нет рекурсии из коробки* В восьмой версии - уже есть. Жаль, автор поленился указать версию своего сервера...

Comment: Используйте иерархические структуры: Nested Sets или Closure Tables.