# Рекурсивная процедура

Tags: mysql, sql

По сути мне нужна была рекурсивная функция, но я прочитал что функции в mysql не могут быть рекурсивными, так что сделал процедуру. Только она не работает почему-то...

```
create table test (id int, next_id int null default null);

insert into test values (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, null);

create procedure getLastId(in in_id int, out out_id int)
begin
    set max_sp_recursion_depth = 50;

    select next_id into out_id from test where id = in_id;

    if not out_id is null then
        call getLastId(out_id, out_id);
    end if;
end;

set @out_id = null;

call getLastId(1, @out_id);

select @out_id;
```

Выбирается `null`. А должно `3`. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Вы конечно написали, что если out_id не null то вызывать следующий раз. но в конце концов он становится null этот if конечно не срабатывает. Но тем не менее это не меняет того факта, что out_id уже установился в null ... Вам надо если out_id стал null делать его равным in_id и завершаться

Comment: И кстати рекурсия тут вообще не нужна. То же самое можно спокойно сделать в цикле. Или вообще в запросе, без процедур

Comment: @Mike подскажите как именно?

Comment: Запросом как нибудь так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/613313/194569  Ну а если циклом, то собственно просто цикл с этим же select завершающийся так же по null

Comment: @Mike не получается :( Вот смотрите, так бы я реализовал это на [php](https://jdoodle.com/a/WnB), а так на [mysql](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6vxwGRh7Qr444ESFAK2xai/0), но это почему-то не работает. Какие-то ошибки... Не пойму что они значат. Вроде правильно все. Это циклом. А уж запросом я и вовсе не знаю как можно... Тот запрос что приведен в указанной вами теме выбирает сразу несколько элементов, а мне нужен один.

Comment: Странное у вас там присваивание. конструкции `@next_id = select  ...` быть не может. вы сами себе противоречите. в начале пишите корректно присвоение переменных с SET и :=, а потом почему то начинаете писать без SET и в итоге даже без `:`.

Comment: @Mike честно говоря я просто путаюсь в этих тонкостях переменных. Уж больно их много в mysql. Можно через `declare`, можно через `set`, можно через `:=`, можно через `=`, можно через `into` в запросах... Немудрено запутаться. В конце двоеточие просто потерялось. Но его добавление все-равно ошибки не исправило.

Comment: да нет там никаких тонкостей. если ставите переменную вне запроса то всегда set. и всегда :=. А одиночное равно это сравнение. просто в php присвоение это =, а сравнение ==, а в mysql := и =. и да в процедурах собственные переменные без @ и они объявляются. А переменные с @ глобальные и к процедурам не имеют ни малейшего отношения.

Comment: Ну а запросом просто все лишние строки отфильтровать надо https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/54zpsQqzu1Qas4uUbP7WYJ/0

Comment: @Mike зачем если не секрет там `limit` у вас? Убрал - вроде не сломалось ничего. Да и `@id` проще объявить заранее чем во `from`. У меня вот [так](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/54zpsQqzu1Qas4uUbP7WYJ/1) вышло, вроде работает

Comment: id заранее объявить обычно сложнее, потому что при выполнении этого кода через php вы не сможете за раз передать более 1 запроса. А set - это отдельный запрос. А limit ограничивает максимальную глубину поиска. Без него запрос будет читать всю таблицу test целиком, вне зависимости от того, что для поиска будет использовано только 3 записи

Comment: @Mike 1. Я не говорил что буду это из php использовать. Мне нужен разовый запрос на слив данных. Но пожалуй вы правы - так короче. 2. Это тестовая таблица. В реальной несколько миллионов записей. Так там нужен лимит или нет? Я не очень понял.

Comment: этот запрос эмулирует цикл. Та таблица test, которая в основном from запроса, если присмотреться вообще не используется по назначению (нигде нет ни одного обращения к ее колонкам). Она нужна только что бы получить нужное количество записей, что бы это количество раз выполнить подзапрос. подзапрос всегда будет выполнен столько раз, сколько там записей, другого способа вовремя остановится не существует. Поэтому лимит ставим в то число, сколько максимально итераций нам _может понадобится_.